# TCP message lost when host my C# on (AWS) cloud server

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

My dotnet/c# server is running very well for my Unity game on my local machine.
But when I host it on an online cloud server (AWS EC2 instance) it will result in not all TCP messages arriving at the client side.

Server side method:
git: github.com/IRiViI/TCPmreServer

```
public void SendData(Packet _packet)
        {
            try
            {
                if (socket != null)
                {
                    stream.BeginWrite(_packet.ToArray(), 0, _packet.Length(), null, null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception _ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error sending data to player {id} via TCP: {_ex}");
            }
        }
```

Client side method:git: github.com/IRiViI/TCPmreClient

```
  private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult _result){
  try {
      int _byteLength = stream.EndRead(_result);
      if (_byteLength <= 0){
          client.Disconnect();
          return;
      }

      byte[] _data = new byte[_byteLength];
      Array.Copy(receiveBuffer, _data, _byteLength);
      receivedData.Reset(HandleData(_data)); 
      stream.BeginRead(receiveBuffer, 0, dataBufferSize, ReceiveCallback, null);
  } catch(Exception _ex) {
      Disconnect();
      Debug.Log(_ex);
  }
}

private bool HandleData(byte[] _data){
int _packetLength = 0;
receivedData.SetBytes(_data);

if(receivedData.UnreadLength() >= 4){
    _packetLength = receivedData.ReadInt();
    if (_packetLength <= 0){
        return true;
    }
}
while (_packetLength > 0 && _packetLength <= receivedData.UnreadLength()){
    byte[] _packetBytes = receivedData.ReadBytes(_packetLength);
    ThreadManager.ExecuteOnMainThread(() => {
        using (Packet _packet = new Packet(_packetBytes)){
            int _packetId = _packet.ReadInt();
            client.packetHandlers[_packetId](_packet);
        }
    });    
    _packetLength = 0;
    if(receivedData.UnreadLength() >= 4){
        _packetLength = receivedData.ReadInt();
        if (_packetLength <= 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
if (_packetLength <= 1){
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

It only happens when I send many (100+) messages at the same time. below 100 it usally goes well.

I think the issue might be AWS related (firewall and such). But I would expect to get some error messages when a TCP message could not be send. I'm not able to find any errors. I would have expect this behaviour of UDP but not of TCP.

My question is: How can I increase the amount of messages that can be send or have some message not received callback inorder to handle failed TCP messages.

Update --

The problem seems to be on the client side. I tested my server code on my server at home and the same problem occures as when running my server code on an EC2 AWS instance.

The problem occures when there are multiple tcp packets handled.

At the moment when the tcp handler breaks, I get a packetsLength of 16777216 (which equals 2^24).

```
if(receivedData.UnreadLength() >= 4){
_packetLength = receivedData.ReadInt();
if (_packetLength <= 0){
    return true;
}
Console.WriteLine($"_{_packetLength}");
```

}

Comment: Please show the client side code

Comment: Thing to remember, tcp will break a single send into multiple chunks. You have to make sure your receive code can deal with that

Comment: @pm100 Client side is added

Comment: @pm100 I forgot one import part of the client. I just added it to the question

Comment: Does your code handle receiving a piece of data that contains the second half of the prior message and only the first half of the next in a single invocation of ReceiveCallback?

Comment: Please post a [mre].  For instance, `receivedData` is never declared in your example.  It _looks_ like you're assuming TCP packets never fragment, though it's impossible to know.

Comment: I will make minimal repreducible example. The code that I use is based on the code of this github: https://github.com/tom-weiland/tcp-udp-networking/tree/tutorial-part5.

Comment: @AnonCoward Hereby an isolated part of my code
The client: https://github.com/IRiViI/TCPmreClient
The server: https://github.com/IRiViI/TCPmreServer
I will leave up my server for now so you only need to run the client.
The server sends 1000 TCP messages to the client.
This goes well with local host. 
But it failes with the aws server.

Comment: To me it seems like you've done nothing at all to handle anything other than multiple _whole_ messages within a single receive. If the packet length is more than the bytes you have received, you will need to store it and append the next received set of bytes to it.

Comment: Imagine you send three messages prefixed by a 1-byte length (hex with length as *): `07* 32 94 1A 6B 3F 0A 2F`, then `04* 1F A2 33 42`, and finally `06* 99 FF 32 1A AA 6B`. Now, on the server you might receive `07* 32 94 1A 6B 3F 0A 2F 04* 1F A2 33 42 06* 99 FF 32 1A AA 6B` all at once as a single message, or perhaps you'll receive `07* 32 94 1A 6B 3F 0A 2F 04* 1F` and then `A2 33 42 06* 99 FF 32 1A AA 6B`, or maybe you'll receive `07*`, and then `32 94 1A 6B 3F` followed by `0A 2F 04* 1F A2 33 42 06*` and then finally `99 FF 32 1A AA 6B`. You need to handle these possibilities.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thanks! I think this might be it indeed. I will try to fix it.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar There actually already is a mechanism. receivedData.Reset(HandleData(_data));  HandleData returns false when there is still data. thereby not restting the received data. 
It seems that _packetLength = receivedData.ReadInt(); will get a value of 16777216 (which is 2^24) at the moment the code crashes.